# getting Guid from database

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

Something strange happend, I am no longer able to get the GUID type from my mysql database with the .net entity model.

A while ago i created a database which used Guid's as ID. I created a connection to this database with the entity framework and everything worked fine.

however i lost the database a while ago and i had to create it again, now however, the classes that get created by the entity framework model have a string as ID, not the GUID it used to be.

What type do i need to make my ID's in my mysql database so I can simply do the following:

```
Image.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
EntityModel.Image.Add(Image);
EntityModel.SaveChanges();
```

This used to work fine, now I (obviously) get an error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid' to 'string'"

I cannot remember how I once did it and am wondering if people here could help.
I did read about UUID() but that's not how I did it.
Somehow I've got the feeling mysql updated and somehow it's no longer possible but that seems odd to me.

I did look into this and saw a lot of people suggesting making the id's a binary type in mysql and converting the Guid to it's binary form and storing that. I'm hoping not to write a conversion class to implicitly cast Guid to Binary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary(16) should work with the newer connectors if you use 'Old Guids=true', otherwise it wants to use char(36)

Comment: O really? xD if i wanted to do that i'd have done it, but i don't. if i do that it would mean i would first have to create strings from my guid for every single statement.. It used to work without .tostring() but probably the worst thing is creating guids from my strings...

Comment: Sorry, your question is pretty confusing.  Try setting the field as char(36) or binary(16) and make sure your connection string has "Old Guids=true" in it.  Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Old GUIDS, i think that's what i'm looking for, let me test, sorry for the confusing question.

Comment: Binary(16) should work with the newer connectors if you use 'Old Guids=true', otherwise it wants to use char(36) I think.  Read more about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html

Comment: You are amazing, I had set the Old Guids=true but the varchar(36) was still a string, it had to be Binary(16). if you change your answer i will accept it :)